# How to match a string in python with conditional looping

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, raw-input

I am a beginner in python. I want to ask the user to input his first name. The name should only contain letters A-Z,if not, I want to display an error and request the user to enter the name again until the name is correct. Here is the code am trying. However, The string is not checked even when it contains numbers and special characters. Where am I going wrong??

```
def get_first_name():
try_again = True
while(try_again==True):
    first_name = raw_input("Please enter your first name.")
    if (re.match("^[A-Za-z]+$", first_name)==False):
        try_again = True
    else:
        try_again = False
        return first_name
```

Comment: When comparing things to boolean you don't need to say `x==True`, you can just do `if x`.

Comment: Can you print `first_name` after receiving the raw_input?

Comment: You need to compare the result of `re.match` to `None` using `is` operator. Or simply `first_name.isalpha()` should do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `re`, just use [str.isalpha](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_isalpha.htm)

```
def get_first_name():  
     while True:
        first_name = raw_input("Please enter your first name.")
        if not first_name.isalpha(): # if not all letters, ask for input again
            print "Invalid entry"
            continue
        else: # else all is good, return first_name
            return first_name
In [12]: "foo".isalpha()
Out[12]: True

In [13]: "foo1".isalpha()
Out[13]: False
```

Comment: @mungaihkamau, I am not sure how good I am but good enough to know you don't need `re` ;)

Comment: that was fast, the reputation can tell all

Comment: are you in any social media?

Comment: @mungaihkamau, not really a social media person, think I am one of the  only people in the world that does not use twitter ;)

Comment: @PadraicCunningham too bad,would love to ask a few questions on python in general,not programming.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham and how would I check if the name contains a special character if I wanted the user to enter one?

Comment: @mungaihkamau, one particular special character?

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (re.match("^[A-Za-z]+$", first_name)==False):
```

re.match is returning None when there is no match. None does not equal False.  You could write it like this:

```
 if not re.match("^[A-Za-z]+$", first_name):
```